# Модификация таймера

Tags: javascript, ооп

Есть таймер написанный на ООП. По истечению заданного таймера. страница должна обновляться.

В коде таймер уходит в отрицательные значения.

```js
'use strict';

window.onload = function(e) {

  let t1 = new Timer(60);

  document.querySelector('.res').innerHTML = t1.getTime();
  if (t1.getTime == 0) {
    location.reload();
  }

};

class Timer {
  constructor(t = 60) {
    this.time = t;
  }

  tick() {
    this.time--;
    console.log(this.time);
  };

  run() {
    setInterval(() => {
      this.tick();
    }, 1000);
  };

  getTime() {
    return this.time;
  }

}
```

```html
<div class="res"></div>
```

Comment: что такое ©обновлялась страница

Comment: @qwabra это когда вместо нажатия на F5, страница сама это делает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
"use strict";
class Timer extends EventTarget {
    constructor(_time = 60) {
        super();
        this._time = _time;
        this._interval = null;
    }
    tick() {
        this._time--;
        console.log(this._time);
        if (this._time === 0) {
            if (this._interval)
                clearInterval(this._interval);
            const e = new Event('time');
            this.dispatchEvent(e);
        }
    }
    run() {
        this._interval = setInterval(() => {
            this.tick();
        }, 1000);
    }
    ;
    getTime() {
        return this._time;
    }
}
const t = new Timer(8);
t.addEventListener('time', () => {
    console.log('Show Must Go On');
});
t.run();
```

[песочница, TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=38&pc=8#code/MYGwhgzhAEAqCWBbApgJ2sgHgF2QOwBMYBRAN321jFQHNltoBvAWACgBIAB1XlLF2gB9eHlyo%20IAFzQ8AV0QAjNNAA%20M2SBDQAvOs0BuNm3bAA9ngjZUs4NlOoAFMa48%20AwdiTId0AGwAGYwBKJmcIWU40ByDjAF8jDm5efm9PYABraNCOdmwAC3gIADoPLwBaMsMcswtTEGQikFMaB3zCks8UIKr2dngAM2hWguLSlB1tXX8Qlhy%20weH24VE0CRDQZGoASRXxMBBF0ZExNecTc0sMHzxkAHdoMgoHAHJO5GeYubbigkLOfmAeUeogcyE%20vXiHEhxmseCys163xKx1W%20x8EHoOxO%20wcWW0AD5sr1ciMimlMt1nLEADTQACM-kZlKhVWMdEoXnhzlQ9FkqDw0CRY2QPWhrDFNUuDF0N3uCBQjgAHJ82NgimACARgdgADKFXA3RyvLzPWl4wkIyV1BpNFrPADKeVM9wAsrJLgBxUzQADyeA%20bFiKtYath0SAA)

Answer (score 1):

```
  let t1 = new Timer(60);
  t1.addEventListener(t => {
    document.querySelector('.res').innerHTML = t.getTime();
    if (t.getTime() <= 0)
      location.reload();
  });


class Timer {
  constructor(t = 60) {
    this.time = t;
    this.listeners = [];
  }

  tick() {
    this.time--;
    console.log(this.time);
    this.listeners.forEach(i => i(this));
  }
  ...
  addEventListener(listener) {
    this.listeners.push(listener);
  }
}
```

Comment: по ООП сущность должна делать только что-то одно. В вашем случае она еще и обновляет страницу.

Answer (score 1):

```js
'use strict';

class Timer {
  #time;
  #interval;

  constructor({ time=60, onTick, onDone } = {}) {
    Object.assign(this, { onTick, onDone });
    this.#time = ++time;
  }

  get time() {
    return this.#time;
  }

  tick() {
    if (--this.#time <= 0) {
      if (typeof this.onDone === 'function')
        this.onDone.call(this);
      return clearInterval(this.#interval);
    }
    if (typeof this.onTick === 'function')
      this.onTick.call(this, this.#time);
  }

  run() {
    this.#interval = setInterval(() => this.tick(), 1000);
    this.tick();
  }
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const output = document.querySelector('.res');
  const timer = new Timer({
    time: 15,
    onTick(time) { output.textContent = time; },
    onDone() { window.location.reload(); },
  });
  timer.run();
});
```

```html
<div class="res"></div>
```